# How to remove p tag in Tinymce

Tags: codeigniter, tinymce

ALthough I have used the 'forced_root_block' in my tinymce.init the p tag has not being removed.

Below is my init function

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://tinymce.cachefly.net/4.1/tinymce.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
     selector: "textarea#fulldis",
     mode : "textareas",
     editor_selector : "fulldis",
     setup: function (editor) { editor.on('change', function () {editor.save(); }); },
     forced_root_block : "", 
     force_br_newlines : true,
     force_p_newlines : false,
     toolbar: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify "
});
</script>
```

This is how it seems:

[image]

Any idea on how to remove the "p" as the one circled above.

Comment: Strip tags with p as parameter. You can't trust user input anyways.

Comment: @Alex how can I remove p at least in the view?

Answer (score 3):

Add this line to your init statement.

```
forced_root_block : ""
```

Complete line could be as

```
<script>
     tinymce.init({
                   forced_root_block : "",
                   selector:'textarea'});
</script>
```

Comment: Setting `forced_root_block` to `false` or an empty string is now deprecated https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#forced_root_block

Answer (score 0):

Use it. TinyMce automatically add "

" tag. You can set this option in tinyMce initialization like this on script ...

```
tinyMCE.init({
  mode : "textareas",
  theme : "advanced",
  force_br_newlines : false,
  force_p_newlines : false,
  forced_root_block : '',
});
```

**Or You can use it....**

This should work fine on Chrome also. Which version of TinyMCE are you using?

BTW a dirty hack to solve this is to open tiny_mce_src.js file and look for this

```
forced_root_block : 'p',
```

and set it to

```
forced_root_block : false or just remove the p.
```

Thank You

Comment: hello theres still no change

Comment: Use Second way.

Answer (score 0):

If only want to hide tag showing on tinymce status bar, then need to use this option, at least for v5.x it works:
[elementpath](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#elementpath)